# Persisting all the samples into InfluxDB with JMeter-InfluxDB-Writer 1.1

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, influxdb, grafana

I have setup Jmeter with InfluxDB and Grafana, and adding "JMeter-InfluxDB-Writer 1.1" as mentioned in the documentation link "https://grafana.net/dashboards/1152".

With this, I am seeing some of the samples are missing (shows 8/10 samples for some of the api's) when queried in the InfluxDB although Jmeter Summary report shows 10/10 samples run for all the api's.

Also attaching my infuxDB.conf for any inputs. Please help[image: Dashboard screen]

```
infuxDB.conf -

reporting-disabled = false
bind-address = ":8088"

[meta]
  dir = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.influxdb\\meta"
  retention-autocreate = true
  logging-enabled = true

[data]
  dir = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.influxdb\\data"
  wal-dir = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.influxdb\\wal"
  query-log-enabled = true
  cache-max-memory-size = 1073741824
  cache-snapshot-memory-size = 26214400
  cache-snapshot-write-cold-duration = "10m0s"
  compact-full-write-cold-duration = "4h0m0s"
  max-series-per-database = 1000000
  max-values-per-tag = 100000
  trace-logging-enabled = false

[coordinator]
  write-timeout = "10s"
  max-concurrent-queries = 0
  query-timeout = "0s"
  log-queries-after = "0s"
  max-select-point = 0
  max-select-series = 0
  max-select-buckets = 0

[retention]
  enabled = true
  check-interval = "30m0s"

[shard-precreation]
  enabled = true
  check-interval = "10m0s"
  advance-period = "30m0s"

[admin]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":8083"
  https-enabled = false
  https-certificate = "/etc/ssl/influxdb.pem"

[monitor]
  store-enabled = true
  store-database = "_internal"
  store-interval = "10s"

[subscriber]
  enabled = true
  http-timeout = "60s"
  insecure-skip-verify = false
  ca-certs = ""
  write-concurrency = 40
  write-buffer-size = 1000

[http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":443"
  auth-enabled = false
  log-enabled = true
  write-tracing = false
  pprof-enabled = true
  https-enabled = false
  https-certificate = "/etc/ssl/influxdb.pem"
  https-private-key = ""
  max-row-limit = 10000
  max-connection-limit = 0
  shared-secret = ""
  realm = "InfluxDB"
  unix-socket-enabled = false
  bind-socket = "/var/run/influxdb.sock"

[[graphite]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":2003"
  database = "jmeter"
  retention-policy = ""
  protocol = "tcp"
  batch-size = 5000
  batch-pending = 100
  batch-timeout = "60s"
  consistency-level = "one"
  separator = "."
  udp-read-buffer = 0

[[collectd]]
  enabled = false
  bind-address = ":25826"
  database = "collectd"
  retention-policy = ""
  batch-size = 5000
  batch-pending = 10
  batch-timeout = "10s"
  read-buffer = 0
  typesdb = "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"
  security-level = "none"
  auth-file = "/etc/collectd/auth_file"

[[opentsdb]]
  enabled = false
  bind-address = ":4242"
  database = "opentsdb"
  retention-policy = ""
  consistency-level = "one"
  tls-enabled = false
  certificate = "/etc/ssl/influxdb.pem"
  batch-size = 1000
  batch-pending = 5
  batch-timeout = "1s"
  log-point-errors = truea

[[udp]]
  enabled = false
  bind-address = ":8089"
  database = "udp"
  retention-policy = ""
  batch-size = 5000
  batch-pending = 10
  read-buffer = 0
  batch-timeout = "1s"
  precision = ""

[continuous_queries]
  log-enabled = true
  enabled = true
  run-interval = "1s"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a pagination and its probably set up to show only 8 lines in a page. The other two sample data could be in the page 2.